# Excel- Add numbers in a column given that they're positive and given that they're associated with a value in a row

Tags: excel, vba

Might be complicated, so let me give you some background:

I have a spreadsheet that contains the following data:

1. Column H contains dates from 1794- 2011 (and within ‘H’ there are
   multiple copies of each date for each legislator present in that
   date)
2. Column Q contains scores that range from -1 to 1 I want to
   calculate the average “positive” value in Column Q for each date in
   Column H, and then have it print out.

For example:

```
1794: Average Positive Value : .65, Average Negative:  -.20
1795: Average Positive Value: .75, Average Negative: -.11
```

I've tried searching around to figure out how to do this, but I don't know the search terms relevant.  Would appreciate some assistance.

Thanks!

Comment: A lot easier to do in a database like SQL Server or even Ms Access.

Comment: How are the dates formatted?  I'm assuming dates before 1900 are formatted as text.  Are dates after 1900 formatted as Text or as Excel dates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here us a simple way using ARRAY Formulas. Please see SNAPSHOT

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(IF(($H$1:$H$7=K10)*($Q$1:$Q$7>0),$Q$1:$Q$7)),"")
```

You have to enter this using CTL + SHIFT + ENTER

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A solution without array formulas is to use `SUMPRODUCT`.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(H1:H7=K10),--(Q1:Q7>0),Q1:Q7)/SUMPRODUCT(--(H1:H7=K10),--(Q1:Q7>0))
```

I ripped off Siddharth's example shown below with SUMPRODUCT.

[image]

Comment: True that, array formulas are definitely better suited to the task at hand but can be intimidating.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use SUMIFS/COUNTIFS for this.

for positive values:

```
=sumifs(Q:Q,H:H,1794,Q:Q,">0")/countifs(H:H,1794,Q:Q,">0")
```

for negative values:

```
=sumifs(Q:Q,H:H,1794,Q:Q,"<0")/countifs(H:H,1794,Q:Q,"<0")
```

Comment: +1 Another good way :) Just a suggestion. You might want to add `IFERROR()` else it will give you a `#DIV/0!` if a particular value is not found. For example 1795 in my case below :)

Comment: Yes. IFERROR should be standard practice. So much so that someone should make a macro that wraps/unwraps all formulas in a spreadsheet with IFERROR.

Comment: SUMIFS/COUNTIFS is the equivalent of using AVERAGEIFS, so that would be preferable `=AVERAGEIFS(Q:Q,H:H,1794,Q:Q,">0")`

Comment: Without knowing the version iferror and sumifs/averageifs are best avoided.

Comment: Good call Roger, I have just such a macro ;) It also checks for version and uses if(iserror( for older versions.

Comment: You gotta be kidding @Roger!  Next we will have code that wraps all code with error handling.

Answer (score 0):

This could be considered kind of a hack, but you could just use some hidden columns that have a copied IF formula per data point. To illustrate:

Add another column A which has IF(Q > 0, Q, 0)
 Add another column B which has IF(Q > 0, 1, 0)
 Add another column C which has IF(Q < 0, Q, 0)
 Add another column D which has IF(Q < 0, 1, 0)

Then, to determine the averages, you can simply do a SUM(A) / SUM(B) and SUM(C) / SUM(D) respectively, since it would be the total value divided by the number of true occurances.